# Best way to deploy a small rails app on a tight budget?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services, hosting

I want to play around with deploying a very small rails application.

It's for personal use, so there will be very low traffic and the app itself is just a newly generated rails 4 project with a sqlite db at the moment.

Currently I have a free AWS instance, a github account with the rails project and a domain.

My plan is to follow the amazon guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Is this doable on a free instance or will I need to spend cash on hosting / platform provider?

Ideally I would like to do this for free, or as close to as possible.

Is there a better or easier way to do this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A Linux based AWS micro instance, if you commit to a year, is only going to cost you around $10/month....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently tried to find the same thing for a blog. I found that I didn't qualify for the free instance for AWS because I signed up to S3 years ago. But that heroku has free development boxes.

Basically, you can get this for free:

- a host
- a small database

But you can't get this for free:

- background processing
- permanent up time

The up time thing is the biggest problem for me. Basically if you don't have someone visiting your site regularly, heroku shut it down to re-distribute the cpu cycles. It will start up again if you visit the site, but it does take 20-30 seconds.

If you want permanent up time, you need to buy a second dyno which will cost $35 a month ish.

Comment: With regards to the no background processing - I assume this means no delayed jobs or just no access to crontab? Also, for uptime is it possible to sign up for one of those services that monitors your sites uptime by pinging regularly or would they disallow that? (obviously 30 seconds would time out most clients....)

Comment: Yeah that's right. Because you need to start a daemon/other program up that stays running in the background and polls the queue.

However, I did see someone claim that they only charge by the second used. So you can start and stop them as you need them. And if you're really keen, you can automate that with the heroku api. So you post an image, save it, start the worker dyno, and return from the request. The worker dyno starts up, processes any images in the queue, then if it finds an empty queue it shuts itself down. Sounded pretty clever but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Free Tier only lasts a year. After that you have to pay and it is not very cheap.

You could try out [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com). Running a simple app is free on Heroku. Perfect for your own hobby projects, can be upscaled when it starts to get real.